# What is the proper way to preallocate memory for a function return value that is called many times in a loop?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, c++17

I'm trying to improve my c++ code and trying to improve my coding style.
I want to implement this function that is called multiple times in a loop.

```cpp
Class C {
    double alpha = 0.1;
    std::valarray<double> f(std::valarray<double> const & arr) //called many times in a loop
    {
        return arr * alpha;
    }
}
```

the array passed in is quite large and every time f returns it allocates a brand new array for the return value, really slowing down my code.
I've tried to implement a fix by preallocating a return value for it in the class it is a member of as soon as the size of the arrays are known during execution;

```cpp
Class C {
    double alpha = 0.1;
    std::valarray<double> f_retval;

    void f(std::valarray<double> const & arr) //called many times in a loop
    {
        f_retval = arr * alpha;
    }

    void allocateMembers(int Nx) //known size of the arrays used in the class 
    {
        f_retval = std::valarray<double>(Nx);
    }
}
```

But there must be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could return by passing by non-const reference to preallocate outside of the member function.

```
Class C {
    double alpha = 0.1;
    void f(std::valarray<double> const & arr, std::valarray<double>& result) //called many times in a loop
    {
        result = arr * alpha;
    }
}
```

The caller would then need to create their own preallocated result variable, but then they could reuse that variable during repeated calls to **f**.

```
std::valarray<double> f_retval = std::valarray<double>(Nx);
while (/*some condition*/) {
    myC.f(toModify, f_retval);
    // do something with f_retval
}
```

The advantages that this has over the solution that you suggested include:

- the return-by-reference is more obvious to the user of the member function
- the member function's functionality is more contained (it doesn't require two methods to execute), which also avoids bugs caused by improper usage
- the class itself is less complex

The only potential drawback I can see with return-by-reference is that calling this method requires an extra variable declaration.

Comment: I suppose pass by non-const reference it is then. I was just wondering if there were any other alternatives seeing as we're so often told to avoid passing by non-const reference even though in this situation it seems like clearly the optimal solution.

Comment: I don't know that I'd avoid passing by non-const reference out of hand.  It's a tool and definitely has it's uses, this being a great example.  I do think that it can be abused though and one of its most obvious uses, multiple return values, has other solutions that many find preferable, such as returning a POD struct or a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to speeding this up is eliminating the memory allocations for every call to `f`.  This requires having a `valarray` variable that can be reused.  This can either be a member of `class C` or passed in as a reference parameter.

However, because the `valarray` multiplication operator will always allocate a new `valarray`, there will still be a memory allocation for each call.  If performance is critical you need to roll your own multiplication loop to store the result into the reusable array (possibly resizing it to the correct size, which is essential for the first call).

In addition to not allocating new memory, this can possibly provide extra benefits from cache usage, since the memory is reused and will likely already be in the CPU data cache.